# htaccess/mod_write: Help to understand rewrite rules and rewrite conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules, which I honestly don't quite understand. This great community helped me to write them a long time ago:

```
RewriteEngine On
#1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{QUERY_STRING} \.([^.]+)\.[^.#]+#FB([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/facebook/%1/%2? [L,NE,R=302]
#2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{QUERY_STRING} \.([^.]+)\.[^.#]+#LI([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/linkedin/%1/%2? [L,NE,R=302]
#3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{QUERY_STRING} \.([^.]+)\.[^.#]+#PT([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/pinterest/%1/%2? [L,NE,R=302]
#4
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{QUERY_STRING} \.([^.]+)\.[^.#]+#XN([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/xing/%1/%2? [L,NE,R=302]
#5
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^IG([^&#]+)#(?:.+\.)?([^.]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/instagram/%2/%1 [L,NE,R=302]
#6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.([^.]+)\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^IG([^/]+)/?$ https://www.mysite.de/link/instagram/%1/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA,R=302]
```

Besides lots of other things, I don't get why in rule #5 `%{QUERY_STRING}` and `%{HTTP_HOST}` is swapped compared to the other rules. What does the `#` do within the rewrite condition? Does it function as a separator?
What does rule #6 do in addition to rule #5?

The main problem for now: The following link:

```
https://test.info/IGZSGUFSPSWC?fbclid=PAAaY2XV-SntbX2OtypPe92gVjSldUctufiEup5zBCOCC7rB71MO8JQlc-8F0&e=ATPMSEL2pg5PoJpf1puuGgcr8dPHj-CUM60wGlrTHZ4VGbz5KBIno8SeX_UzO-K1HHjnP8ebBEwdDfWgMGB3Pa1mv6YCLAUzSBvdZQ
```

should be redirected to

```
https://www.mysite.de/link/instagram/datenschutz-impressum/ZSGUFSPSWC
```

but it is redirected to

```
https://www.mysite.de/link/facebook/datenschutz-impressum/clid=PAAaY2XV-SntbX2OtypPe92gVjSldUctufiEup5zBCOCC7rB71MO8JQlc-8F0
```

The query string begins with `fb` so the first rule does apply. I want rule #5 to apply.

**How can this be done?**

I wish you a great new year

Comment: I suggest you switch on rewrite logging. That allows to understand on a step by step level what is actually going on inside your rewrite module. See the documentation of the rewriting module to learn how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> #5
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^IG([^&#]+)#(?:.+\.)?([^.]+)\. [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/instagram/%2/%1 [L,NE,R=302]
> ```
>
> I don't get why in rule #5 `%{QUERY_STRING}` and `%{HTTP_HOST}` is swapped compared to the other rules.

There would not seem to be any good reason for that. Maybe it was written at a different time and it just made sense to do it that way at the time?

Everything is just reversed... the regex and the backreferences in the *substitution* string (ie. `%2` and `%1`).

That rule could be rewritten the same way as the preceding rules like this:

```
#5 (reversed)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:.+\.)?([^.]+)\.[^#]*#IG([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/instagram/%1/%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Note that this rule is subtly different to the preceding rules for some reason, which does look like an error, but may not make any difference (depending on the request). Points of note:

- This rule makes the subdomain *optional* (for single level TLDs), whereas in the preceding rules the subdomain is mandatory. For instance, this rule will match `test.info`, whereas the preceding rules will not, since they are expecting a subdomain like `www.test.info`. So I doubt that `test.info` is an accurate "exemplified" hostname in your example?
- This rule only permits a single URL parameter that starts `IG` followed by *something*. Whereas the earlier rules match the two character *code* followed by *anything* (incl. *nothing*) and any other URL parameters (which are simply discarded).
- This rule also *preserves* the query string, whereas the preceding rules discard it. This looks like an oversight/error?

> What does the `#` do within the rewrite condition? Does it function as a separator?

Yes, it's simply a separator between the two parts of the URL. Which effectively allows two *conditions* to be combined in order to capture backreferences from both. Any character could be used here that does not occur in either the *hostname* or the *query string* parts of the URL.

> What does rule #6 do in addition to rule #5?

Rule #6 checks the URL-path instead of the query string (in rule #5). In fact, it's this rule that should be triggered for your example URL, not rule #5.

In other words, rule #5 would match `/anything?IGX`, whereas rule #6 matches `/IGX`.

#### Solution

> The query string begins with `fb` so the first rule does apply. I want rule #5 to apply.

(Except, as mentioned above, `test.info` would not match, and rule #6 should apply here, not rule #5.)

I would question whether you need the `NC` (case-insensitive) flag on all the preceding *conditions*? Do you need to match `fb` in the query string in the first rule, or just `FB` as stated in the regex? Removing the `NC` would resolve the immediate problem you are experiencing.

Otherwise, you need to change the order of the rules so that rule #6 is first and therefore takes priority over rule #1.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA,R=302]
> ```

This 302 redirects anything that would ordinarily trigger a 404 to root (ie. the "homepage"). This isn't generally recommended for SEO or users. However, this is more easily achieved with the following *core* directive, which will do the same thing:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/
```

Logically, this should be defined at the top of the file, but the order does not really matter.